# How to scrape all the pages and Upload the scraped data into excel in the required format using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here I am trying to scrape the teacher jobs from the https://www.indeed.co.in/?r=us I want to get that uploaded to the excel sheet like jobtitle, institute/school, salary, howmanydaysagoposted 
I wrote the code for scraping like this but I am getting all the text from the xpath which I defined

```
import selenium.webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions


url = 'https://www.indeed.co.in/?r=us'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"mypython/bin/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-input-what"]').send_keys("teacher")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="whatWhereFormId"]/div[3]/button').click()


items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultsCol"]')
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
```

And even I am able to scrape only one page and I want all the pages that are available after I search for teacher
Please help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: what problem you are facing in the above code?

Comment: I am getting all the text from this webpage https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=teacher&l= like upload your resume and even 123456 text also and also I need all the pages data but getting only one page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, don't forget to import selenium modules

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://www.indeed.co.in/?r=us'

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-input-what"]').send_keys("teacher")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="whatWhereFormId"]/div[3]/button').click()

 # scrape data
 data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
          EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol")))
 result_set = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "jobsearch-SerpJobCard")))

for result in result_set:
    data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol")))
    result_set = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "jobsearch-SerpJobCard")))

    for result in result_set:

        title = result.find_element_by_class_name("title").text
        print(title)

        school = result.find_element_by_class_name("company").text
        print(school)

        try:
           salary = result.find_element_by_class_name("salary").text
           print(salary)

        except:
           # some result set has no salary
           pass
        print("--------")

   # move to next page
   next_page = result.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='pn']")[-1]
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page)
```

Comment: tried your code 
got this error
Hindi Teacher (PRT)
Shiksha Valley School, Dibrugarh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jobs.py", line 36, in <module>
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "salary"))).text
  File "/home/nyros/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: have you added try-except in getting salary element? as I have already mentioned in the answer, because some data have no salary data.

Comment: Yes now I added sorry I got it can you say why I didnt get

Comment: Why you used until_wait

Comment: you can get `title`, `school`, `salary` without adding wait, after submit search result page is loading so I have added wait for getting element `data`

Comment: accept the answer, if it's useful. you can check here:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-excel-sheet-using-python/

Comment: yes accepted thankyou but how can I upload these using selenium I asked not the other library

Comment: I also asked how to scrape all pages please help me only getting one page details now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209042/discussion-between-manali-kagathara-and-stack).

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage you to checkout beautiful soup https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/
I've used this for scraping tables,

```
def read_table(table):
    """Read an IP Address table.
    Args:
      table: the Soup <table> element
    Returns:
      None if the table isn't an IP Address table, otherwise a list of
        the IP Address:port values.
    """
    header = None
    rows = []
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        if header is None:
            header = read_header(tr)
            if not header or header[0] != 'IP Address':
                return None
        else:
            row = read_row(tr)
            if row:
                rows.append('{}:{}'.format(row[0], row[1]))
    return rows
```

Here is just a snippet from one of my python projects https://github.com/backslash/WebScrapers/blob/master/us-proxy-scraper/us-proxy.py
You can use beautiful soup to scrape tables incredibly easily, if your worried about it getting blocked then you just need to send the right headers. Also another advantage to using beautiful soup is that you don't have to wait as long for a lot of stuff.

```
HEADERS = requests.utils.default_headers()
HEADERS.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})
```

Best of luck

Comment: Can I use both beautifulsoup and selenium in one script @Backslash

Comment: Can you say any changes in my code for achieving this I cant change the entire code nor

Comment: @stack yes you can actually, i've worked with that before I don't have any published code snippets however so I recommend you read something like this: https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-99195cd70a58

Comment: @stack I'd honestly rewrite your whole code and just use beautiful soup, especially when working with webscraping adding unnecessary just makes your code slower.

Comment: But why cant I achieve this using selenium??

Comment: @stack you can and we are different devs, I would personally never use selenium for webscraping unless I was writing something incredibly complex that required user interaction. You seem to just be scraping text from tables (if im not mistaken). Its incredibly easy to scrape text with selenium. I encourage you to do a bit more research into beautiful soup. Another reason I don't recommend selenium for webscraping is that its high cpu and also very slow for startup and doesnt have multithreading.

Comment: Here i used user interaction for searching teacher job and clicking search button thats why I used selenium @Backslash

Comment: @stack you don't need to though ;) you can just use the search query: https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=teacher&l=your-state-here

Comment: no problem, if you need anymore help with your project feel free to dm me on telegram: @backslas

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to nevigate to every page and **scrape** them one by one i.e. you'll have to automate click on next page button in selenium(use xpath of Next Page button element). Then extract using page source function.
Hope I could help.

Comment: So like I used the click() for button in my code I should use for next right how can I It will be fine if you show an example for that @user9113784

Comment: @stack if you can do it for first page then manually wait for some seconds to load the next page or automate it by locating next page button element using try and except block if you don't want use timer.

Comment: @stack I don't have laptop right nowand I'm am replying by phone. I can explain with code after sometime.